# Finding area of Resultant triangles of Delaunay trianglulation

Tags: matlab, area, triangulation, delaunay

After applying delaunay triangulation is it possible to find the area of each triangles formed? Is there any function in matlab to do it? Kindly clarify me. Advance thanks

Comment: you can write your own. Check the output of [`delauny`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunay.html). It gives you indices of points. Then you can calculate 3 sides and use [this](http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/herons-formula.html) formula.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same doubt but thankfully, I was able to crack it, try this:

```
tri = delaunay(x,y);
areas = polyarea(x(tri'),y(tri'),2);
```

This will give you areas of each triangle formed.

Do let me know if you find any difficulties.

P.S: the `tri'` means the transpose of the matrix.

Comment: Hi... thnx fr ur reply...but i have 160 triangles. i need to find the area of all the triangles... i could not get the answer with the above code

Comment: Hi,
I wonder why would that be, the vector areas would be an 160*1 vector in your case. If you want you can view the same in the workspace. 
Lastly, the indexing of the vector would be the same as that of tri. 
Please feel free to ask more if needed :)

Comment: Just for clarification... by `area of all the triangles` you mean area of each triangle or sum of area of all triangles ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [polyarea](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/polyarea.html) - note the use of the `dim` option.

```
tri = delaunay(x,y);
areas = polyarea(tri(x),tri(y),2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works, but is not vectorized.

```
DT = delaunayTriangulation(X,Y);

NTriangles = size(DT.ConnectivityList,1);

% Triangles' Area Calculation (Try to vectorize)
Areas = zeros(NTriangles,1);
for i = 1:NTriangles
    PointIndexes = DT.ConnectivityList(i,:);
    Areas(i) = polyarea(DT.Points(PointIndexes,1),DT.Points(PointIndexes,2));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers here were close to true in my case, but not quite, so I add my voice to the discussion for future people who may need it.

When trying the solutions given here I got the following error:

```
Error using reshape
Number of elements must not change. Use [] as one of the size inputs to
automatically calculate the appropriate size for that dimension.

Error in polyarea (line 46)
  area = reshape(abs(sum( (x([2:siz(1) 1],:) - x(:,:)).* ...
```

The problem was that `x(tri')` gave a vector, and not a matrix. Instead, I did the following:

```
pt = tri.Points;
conn = tri.ConnectivityList;
xmat = reshape(pt(conn,1), [], 2);
ymat = reshape(pt(conn,2), [], 2);
Avec = polyarea(xmat, ymat, 2);
```

And this solved my problem, while still being a vectorized operation.